# SQL Server Is there any impact if we keep the TRAN open for the SELECT and UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, locking

I came across a procedure where TRANSACTION has been kept open, here is the snippet

```
BEGIN TRAN
--Lot of select queries to process the business logic, lets assume 30 seconds to generate the @Par3 and @Par4 as they are having XML data

   IF 1= 1
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Table  SET Col1= 'Value' WHERE Col2=@Par1 AND Col3 = @Par4
            UPDATE Table2  SET Col5= 'Value' WHERE Col2=@Par1 AND Col3 = @Par4
        END
   COMMIT
```

I would like to know if the above code will lock the tables which are in SELECT clause. I am planning to add the TRANSACTION only before the UPDATE.

Is the below code is better than the above one

```
  BEGIN
       --Lot of select queries to process the business logic, lets assume 30 seconds to generate the @Par3 and @Par4 as they are having XML data
       IF 1= 1
          BEGIN
              BEGIN TRAN
                    UPDATE Table  SET Col1= 'Value' WHERE Col2=@Par1 AND Col3 = @Par4
                    UPDATE Table2  SET Col5= 'Value' WHERE Col2=@Par1 AND Col3 = @Par4
                    COMMIT
          END
```

Please let me know if it makes any difference.

Comment: Transactions are there to provide the [ACID properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID_(computer_science)). Without knowing what this logic is doing, moving the transaction boundaries might easily now be breaking any *consistency* expectations. (Also, there's not much point in wrapping a single statement in a transaction since SQL Server already does that for every DML statement outside of an open transaction and commits it automatically, by default)

Comment: Transaction is always present. Locks are also always present.

Comment: There is no point in using transaction for single DML.At the time same Transaction scope should be as small as possible. So If there were more than one DML then you are right.

Comment: Hi, There are multiple UPDATE Statements present in the TRANSACTION. I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

The default isolation level should be `READ COMMITTED`. Without having `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` set to ON, your select may be blocked if in another transaction some updates/deletes/inserts are done. This depends on which locks are used which depends on the data you touch.

Both statemenmts should be equal as without specifing any transaction, SQL server creates one on its own and should use the default isolation level.

Comment: Imagine following sql: `begin transaction
select * from Table_1 where table_1.col1 = 1
-- break --
update Table_1 set table_1.col1 = 22 where col1 = 1` execute until the break, then execute in another window `update table_1 set col1 = 22 where col1 = 1` and you get the same. The results, selected in the first transaction, have changed. As in `READ COMMITTED`shared locks are not hold until transaction ends, both statements should behave equal. Where is the mistake on my part? // Edit: This was an answer to a comment that is missing now?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback...We have read committed snapshot as the Isolation level. We are having a deadlock issue in the procedure where above code snippet is present. Wanted to confirm that is it may be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRAN
      UPDATE Table  SET Col1= 'Value' WHERE Col2=@Par1 AND Col3 = @Par4
COMMIT
```

has no sense at all as by default `SQL Server` operates in `autocommit mode`, this means that there is no need to wrap single `UPDATE` statement in `begin tran`..`commit`, it will be committed automatically.

The original code opens a `transaction` for doing **multiple** `update`s, this mean that business logic requires **all** these `update`s to be committed or **all** to be rolled back if something goes wrong.

```
I would like to know if the above code will lock the tables which are in SELECT clause
```

This depends on your `SELECT`s and on the table structure. If your table has an index on `col2` or `col3` and your `SELECT`s do not touch the same rows or use `readpast` there will be no conflict.